# Why does Google Earth show incorrect images when using google hosted images

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Earth often seems to load random images instead of the ones specified in kml. For example load the kml sample from the kml documentation for IconStyle (https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#iconstyle) It specifies the image at http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon21.png which when viewed in a browser is a building on a green field, but in earth shows up as mountains.

Seems almost as though earth is hard coded to use an internal palette whenever a google hosted image is found and the palettes have gotten out of sync.

(Earth version is 6.2.1.6014 (beta))

Comment: Loading KML generated by others so suggestions to use different URL's for images unfortunately wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a unfortunate legacy issue.

Google Maps at one point changed around their icons - reusing the same filenames!

Google Earth on the other hand knows that many users where using the specific icons in their Places and KML files. So rather than everybodies icons suddenly changing randomly, they choose to still show the old icons.

Would be funny if it wasn't true!

---

If you really want to use Google hosted icons, you could use an alternative URL - one that hopefully Google Earth wont attempt to 'fix', eg http://googleapis.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon21.png

But really would not recommend relying on Google Hosted icons. They can change at any point.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to have any problem download the icons you want to use and create a KMZ layer instead of KML. Like that you will be able to have a folder with your images inside and you won't be depending on the hosted ones.